# Python 2.7 Selenium - How to get all elements on a webpage?

Tags: python, css, selenium, xpath, element

```
from selenium import webdriver

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.set_window_size(1400, 1000)
driver.get('')

def get_list_of_all_elements(self):
    list_of_elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*')

    for ele in list_of_elements:
        print ele
```

I want my code to print out the elements on the page, the code works except it doesnt print anything out and idk why. To be more specific, ideally I dont want every element on the page, just a set a possible images that I locate using `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@title='']")`  the title varies from image to image, and they dont have a class/type/etc so I either have to use xpath or css selector. Any help is appreciated =).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you really want all elements, why not just open the page source in a browser? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can also print driver.page_source if you want to look up the page source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to give it time to load the page by introducing an explicit wait. For instance, you can wait for at least one `img` element to appear on the page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "img"))
)

list_of_elements = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('img[title]')
# ...
```